# Document Classification with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just started with TensorFlow and python and need some help on how I can solve my problem. I want to do a document classification with TensorFlow. I have 20 different document classifications. As model, I think that CNN is what I need.

For the training I have the following datasets:

image --> image of the document

the ocr of the image is already done so I got

textdata --> contains all words found by the OCR (bag of words?)

position.xml --> the position of the word i.e.:

`<postion text="This" page="1" left="234" top="250" right="388" bottom="304" TY="0" TX="17" conf="100" /> 
 <postion text="is" page="1" left="505" top="295" right="849" bottom="349" TY="0" TX="37" conf="93" />
  <postion text="a" page="1" left="865" top="295" right="997" bottom="338" TY="0" TX="62" conf="100" />
  <postion text="test" page="1" left="1425" top="291" right="1752" bottom="333" TY="0" TX="102" conf="100" />`

Classification --> what class the document is (95 % correct) 
by manual verification

I have at least 20.000 datasets where all information above where given.

for the test, the classification dataset is missing. Can someone give me some tips on how I can solve the problem? I have no code written because I don't know how to start with the given information.

Answer (score 2):

on a very high level, you can treat the problem as *supervised classification* where each document (*example*) is associated with a single class (*label*). Your dataset contains some 20k labeled examples (and you have some unlabeled test data). For the first experiments, you can focus only on your labeled examples, because it allows you to evaluate your classifier.

There is a plenty of literature on document classification, but since you want to do it in TF, there are few tips how to start.

- You can either split your data in *training*, *development*, and *test* set or perform *cross-validation*. For the former, either `tensorflow-datasets` package or simply `tf.data.Dataset` might be helpful.
- As of your model, you can try a simple bag-of-words, but TF has advanced models (such as Long Short-Term Memory, LSTM) at your fingertips.

Here are a few good starting points:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/text

  - Essentialy the answer to your question; you only have to load your data into `tf.data.Dataset` which might be not that trivial as this tutorial makes few shortcuts here
- The tutorial on text classification with pre-processed data might also come helpful

  - https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification
- If you want to first convert your data to `tfds.core.DatasetBuilder` to be easily integrated, have a look at, for example, at:

  - https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/tensorflow_datasets/text/imdb.py (but this is rather advanced if you lack experience with TF)

Hope it helps!